# Execute array push statement in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, push

i have a problem with the variable and want to use it as array_push.

this is my variable

```
$QueryStmtPart6 = "(int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05']";
```

i want to use as if in

```
array_push($jsonData,array( $doc['ESN'],(int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05'] ));
```

but instead of using that string. i want to use a variable.
something like this

```
array_push($jsonData,array($doc['ESN'], $QueryStmtPart6 ));
```

but i have an error with this as it will insert become like this

```
0 => array:2 [▼
0 => "ESN1"
1 => "(int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05']" ]
```

this is what i want

```
0 => array:4 [▼
0 => "ESN1"
1 => 0
2 => 1
3 => 0 ]
```

i also have tried with this

```
array_push($jsonData,array($doc['ESN'], $$QueryStmtPart6 ));
```

but it give me error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: (int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05']
```

This is how i retrieve the data from MySQL

```
  $QueryStmtPart5 =  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('(int) &&doc [''',Location,''']' )) AS str_arraypush FROM vwrpt;
```

once execute i got this

```
$QueryStmtPart6 = (int) &&doc ['G03'],(int) &&doc ['G04'],(int) &&doc ['G05']
```

and i replace the && with $ sign as per below

```
$QueryStmtPart6 = str_replace("&&","$",$QueryStmtPart6);
```

so the final result will be

```
$QueryStmtPart6= "(int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05']";
```

Comment: Make sure you understand difference between array and string.

Comment: is this workable for my case? is there any workaround for this. as QueryStmtPart6 will be dynamic. it will have different number of element.

Comment: If all values come from `$doc`, then you can use a list of the element names and do it that way - perhaps `G03,G04,G05`.

Comment: @NigelRen im not sure how to do that. can give me example? thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the variable directly, and assuming all of the values are from the same array, you can do it in two parts.

First in your SQL, just get a comma separated list of the items you want...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Location )) AS locations 
    FROM vwrpt;
```

may do it.  And you should end up with something like...

```
$QueryStmtPart6 = "G03,G04,G05";
```

(Just for test data I've used...

```
$doc = [ "G01" => 1,"G02" => 2,"G03" => 3,"G04" => 4,"G05" => 5,"G06" => 6 ];
```

)

Now take the string you've got from the database, `explode()` it into an array split by the comma.  I use `array_flip()` so that these values then become the keys)...

```
$elements = array_flip(explode(",", $QueryStmtPart6));
```

Then use `array_intersect_key()` to extract the items in `$doc`, which match the keys in your database.

```
print_r( array_intersect_key($doc, $elements));
```

For the test data I've used, this gives...

```
Array
(
    [G03] => 3
    [G04] => 4
    [G05] => 5
)
```

To add a new item to it with a key, you would need to do something like...

```
$results = array_intersect_key($doc, $elements);

$results['ESN'] = "ESN1";
```

Comment: wow. that was great! thanks. but how do i push the $doc['ESN'] as in array_push($jsonData,array($doc['ESN'], $QueryStmtPart6 )); ?
so that the array will be 
Array
(
    [ESN] = > ESN1
    [G03] => 3
    [G04] => 4
    [G05] => 5
)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by @u_mulder, your variable `$QueryStmtPart6` contains a string. You probably want to use an array instead. Like this:

```
$QueryStmtPart6 = [(int) $doc ['G03'], (int) $doc ['G04'], (int) $doc ['G05']];
```

Another point is that the function `array_push` is a variadic function, which means it takes a variable number of arguments. And more importantly, each argument is added as a single item into an array. If an argument is an array, the function will map a new key to the complete array. That is the case in your example.

To avoid this, if you are using recent enough PHP version, you should apply argument unpacking and turn the code into

```
array_push($jsonData, $doc['ESN'], ...$QueryStmtPart6);
```

Note the ellipsis ('...'). It takes each value from your array and passes it as a separate argument to the function `array_push`.

Comment: this can solve my problem. thanks a lot. but fyi, my $QueryStmtPart6 i fetch from MySQL. that's why it become string. does that mean i have to make it as array?

Comment: @Norain You have the exact string literal "(int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05']" stored in a MySQL column?

Comment: yes. i execute the MySQL query and  "(int) $doc ['G03'],(int) $doc ['G04'],(int) $doc ['G05']"  is the result i got from it. G04, G05 and G03 is from my table i do the concatenate to get the string. FYI, G04,G03,G05 is dynamic, it wont fix to only 3. but might have more or less and with different value.

Comment: @Norain Could you provide just a small part of your code that retrieves the results from MySQL?

Comment: hi.. i already edit my question above. is that sufficient enough?